# C++ importing file from command line in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, command-line, argc

I am new to using the command line to start up a program. I want to call my file, called "file.txt". I've been searching for examples but I have not seen what the command line writes.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        cerr << "Error: file name argument not given" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    ifstream inFile( argv[1], ios::in);
}
```

Got it. So through the command line I navigate to my .exe and call the file I want after.

```
C:\Users\me\sampleProject\bin\Debug>test.exe sampleFile.txt
```

And it works.

Thanks.

Comment: `ifstream`..., `ios::in`... Better safe than sorry, eh?

Comment: Have you installed an external compiler or are you using dev studios compiler?

Comment: CodeBlocks with GNU GCC compiler.

Comment: @Nexus: It's ok to answer your own question, but could you put your answer down VVV there ? It's very confusing now that you've added the answer as part of the question.